# How do I avoid a potential infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I cannot understand why my function exceeds time limit and why it can go into an infinite loop. Is there an edge case I might be overlooking?

Here is the problem description:

**Given a sorted array of distinct integers and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.**

```js
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
  if (target > nums[nums.length - 1]) { // If target is greater 
    return nums.length;                 // than the largest element
  };
  let leftIndex = 0;                   // implementing binary search
  let rightIndex = nums.length - 1;
  while (leftIndex != rightIndex) {
    let pivot = Math.round((rightIndex + leftIndex) / 2);
    if (target == nums[pivot]) {
      return pivot;
    } else if (target < nums[pivot]){
        rightIndex = pivot - 1; 
    } else {
        leftIndex = pivot + 1;
    }
  };
  return target <= nums[leftIndex] ? leftIndex : leftIndex + 1;
};
```

Comment: what is the function doing? please add the call and result, you expect.

Comment: Just a tip... convert the code into something humans understand. No criticism, but this type of code in its current form makes the problem much harder to understand than it probably really is. Descriptive variable names, split up in descriptive functions if necessary.

Comment: I added you a confirm so you can see the code does not advance. Please change the last line to something realistic

Comment: Since the `while` strictly checks for inequality, there is a possible situation where the `leftIndex` has become greater than the `rightIndex`. If this happens, then it is a potential infinite-loop (because no where within the `while` is the `leftIndex` decreased or `rightIndex` increased). Try changing to `while (leftIndex < rightIndex)` - it will prevent infinite-loop, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a condition which really stops the loop, for example by checking left and right and if left is greater than right exit the loop.

```
while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
```

Another part is to floor the pivot index, either by using [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) or by [`>>` right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift).

```
const pivot = (rightIndex + leftIndex) >> 1; // right shift by one bit
```

This prevents to omit some indices and produces predictable results.

To check all use an array with even and odd items and check every value of the array.

```js
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
    let leftIndex = 0;
    let rightIndex = nums.length - 1;

    if (target > nums[rightIndex]) return nums.length;                 

    while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
        const pivot = (rightIndex + leftIndex) >> 1;

        if (target === nums[pivot]) return pivot;

        if (target < nums[pivot]) rightIndex = pivot - 1; 
        else leftIndex = pivot + 1;
    };
    return target <= nums[leftIndex] ? leftIndex : leftIndex + 1;
};

console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -0.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5.5));
console.log('--');
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], -0.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 0));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 0.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 5.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 6));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 6.5));
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 7));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 6, 8, 10, 16, 18, 20, 33, 55]

function findTarget(target){
  if(array.includes(target)){
    return "Target was found at index : " + array.indexOf(target)
  }
  if(array[0] > target)
    return "Target should be inserted at index : " + 0
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=1){
    if(array[i] < target && array[i + 1] > target){
      return "Target should be inserted at index : " + (i+1)
    }
  }
  return "Target should be inserted at index : " + array.length
}

console.log(findTarget(8))
console.log(findTarget(9))
console.log(findTarget(60))
console.log(findTarget(0))
```